# How to drag&drop SVG <g> <path>

Tags: javascript, svg

I want to drag svg element  element
But, I don't know "How to use function in `<script>`"
And, I don't know where I write "ondrop, ondrag etc"

this is Puzzle game , so I want to drag this Puzzle(path).

```
<g > 
 <path id="forward" 
                        fill="#6ED7DB"
                        d="m10,70.68377l31.76814,-0.09769l0,22.85714l25.61947,0l0,-23.44322l135.61239,0l0,61.53847l-131.85487,0l0,18.46155l-26.64425,-0.29305l0,-19.34067l-34.50088,0l0,-59.68253z"
                        stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null"
                        stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="2" stroke="#b6d6d6" 
                        fill="#aaffff"   
                        /></path>  

        <text class="blocklyText" transform="translate(24,120)"
        font-size="23px">앞으로&nbsp;움직이기</text>
</g> 

<g >
<path
        d="m346.5679,120.66669l0.38065,-22.14957l-44.97269,1l-0.97586,-44.95058l43.91376,-18.56654l239.14142,0.97719l-0.05536,60.58553l-213.8244,0.95441l-0.9205,21.49808l-22.68701,0.65149z"
            id="svg_7" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null"
            stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="2" stroke="#b6d6d6"
            fill="#ff7f00" />

<text class="blocklyText" transform="translate(310,86)"
        font-size="23px">IF you click</text>
</g>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several javascript libraries which support drag & drop of SVG elements (eg. Snap, Raphael, D3).  Check the documentation of each of those libraries for instructions on how to do dragging.

Comment: Thank you For your answer!! but...I hard use js.

Comment: function drag(target, mySVG) {  
  mySVG.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', mySVG.target.id);
 };
 function drop(target, mySVG) {  
  var id = mySVG.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
  mySVG.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(id));
  mySVG.preventDefault();
 }